# 'PointerType' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvmlite

I'm trying convert this raw LLVM code:

```
%UnwEx = type { i64, i8*, i64, i64 }
@UnwEx.size = constant i64 ptrtoint (%UnwEx* getelementptr (%UnwEx* null, i32 1) to i64)
```

To the llvmlite:

```
unw_ex = context.get_identified_type("UnwEx")
unw_ex.elements = [int_, i8_ptr, int_, int_]
i32 = ir.IntType(32)
gep = builder.gep(ir.PointerType(unw_ex), [i32(1)], name="gep")
... # some extra code to cast gep to integer
```

The idea is get the size of the structured type `UnwEx` in runtime. However the last line with `get` command raise this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DavidRagazzi/Desktop/mamba/mamba/core/runtime.py", line 495, in <module>
    generate(None, 64, 8)
  File "C:/Users/DavidRagazzi/Desktop/mamba/mamba/core/runtime.py", line 280, in generate
    gep = builder.gep(unw_ex_ptr, [i32(1)], name="gep")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ir\builder.py", line 925, in gep
    inbounds=inbounds, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ir\instructions.py", line 494, in __init__
    typ = ptr.type
AttributeError: 'PointerType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

What's wrong with this? Is there a better way to get the size of type?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [gep](https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/ir/ir-builder.html#llvmlite.ir.IRBuilder.gep) should be a value that is pointer to an instance `UnwEx`. What you're passing is a *type*, not a value. The way you get that pointer is by allocating memory using [alloca](https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/ir/ir-builder.html#llvmlite.ir.IRBuilder.alloca) or `malloc` (in which case you'd have to bitcast the returned pointer to `UnwEx*`).

Another way of getting `UnwEx`'s size is by using its [get_abi_size](https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/ir/types.html#llvmlite.ir.Type.get_abi_size) member. Something like

```
target = llvmlite.binding.Target.from_default_triple()
target_machine = target.create_target_machine()
unw_ex_size = unw_ex.get_abi_size(target_machine.target_data)
```

gives you the size of in bytes an instance of `UnwEx` would occupy on your host platform.

Comment: Yep, get_abi_size was the trick to solve my problem a time ago. Anyway your answer is useful to people facing the same problem. Thanks!